# Android Studio - Where is application folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm fresh starting out Android development. Just downloaded Android Studio 3.5 and am trying to follow various tutorials that tell me to look at the files within the [application] folder; however, my project manager folder looks different than all the tutorials. Even different than what it should look like on the android download site.

Mine:

[image]

What it looks like on android docs tutorial:

[image]

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project).

Answer (score 3):

it looks different because you probably imported the parent directory to android studio not the app itself, but you can still access the app folder from where you are now

Answer (score 2):

there's app folder below .idea, open it.
above FirstAndroidApp you can see Android with a drop down arrow, select it and choose the level you want to see.

Comment: Even then inside of that folder, it's not close to the same as it should look. I'm wondering is it because I set up my Android Studio incorrectly perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your 'app' folder hierarchy? That would help us see the difference

Comment: @geistmate the structure of the project varies from gradle versions to others, can also depend on android studio version, or IDE settings or project importing. I've seen some difference in my friend's IDE on mac too. but this is not a serious problem to care about since you can access your app folder and find your classes.

Comment: @geistmate your classes are located in project -> app -> src -> main -> java -> com.example... or res folder

Comment: @TamimAttafi Alright I'm seeing it and starting to understand it now as I read some more; I can find all the files at least. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you incorrectly set up your Android Studio project. See the green dot by your `FirstAndroidApp` folder? In the tutorial, `app` has that green dot. This indicates what Android Studio calls a "module". I suggest you start from the beginning of the tutorial to figure out what detail you missed to set up the `app` module.

Answer (score 0):

In your project view, MainActivity is located inside the 'app' folder.

If you look at the 2nd given picture, it shows the app folder opened at the top which means it's probably the same structure for your project.

Just navigate down that folder (non-generated folders) and you'll find it

Answer (score 0):

You have not made any errors but your starting point is different.

Inside the **app** folder ***located just below `.idea` folder.***

You will find the **java** sub-folder which contains the `MainActivity.java` file.